# Elasticsearch Multiple Rails Models Size for each

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, elasticsearch

I am using elasticsearch to search across multiple rails models like so:

```
Elasticsearch::Model.search(query, [], size: 50)
```

This works great!

What I would like to do, is limit the number of each model type that comes through. For example, there are 4 models that are searchable, and I would like no more than 5 of each to come through, with a total of up to 20 results.

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-sampler-aggregation.html and max_doc_per_value ?

Comment: @alkuzad How would I apply this in rails? I tried doing something like: `Elasticsearch::Model.search(query, [], size: 50, aggs: {sample: { sampler: { max_docs_per_value: 5 }}})` but no dice. I get `<ArgumentError: URL parameter 'aggs' is not supported>`

Comment: i would first try to create raw post and then try to convert it to ror wrapper. Perhaps this library has some raw function